# How to remove dash (-) and \n at the same time or some solution to this text cleaning

Tags: r

I have been trying to remove dash(-) and \n for quite sometimes and it is not working.

I have tried using this code to remove -

```
gsub(" - ", " ", df1$text)
```

I have also tried using this code to remove \n

```
gsub("[\n]", " ", df1$text)
```

However, when I remove \n it becomes "abc-" when I remove dash(-), it becomes "abc\n". Is just a loop. All this result is in the console

*When I try using \n to remove. In the console result*

```
Df1

Id  text
1   I have learnt abc-d in school.
2   I want app-le.
3   Going to sc-hool is fun.
```

*When I try using dash(-) to remove. In console result*

```
Df1

Id  text
1   I have learnt abc\nd in school.
2   I want app\nle.
3   Going to sc\nhool is fun.
```

This is just loop and loop. I tried \n remove then dash(-) remove and all over again.

*This is the data in dataframe. (It always stays the same)*

```
Id  text
1   I have learnt abc- d in school.
2   I want app- le.
3   Going to sc- hool is fun
```

For the dataframe right after the dash(-) there is a space.

The data I am using is news article, I have copyed and pasted it in a excel file. But I try using r to clean it.

Could someone help me out with this. Thanks!

I don't mind sharing the data with you privately, but just do not disclose it. Because it is my school project.

Answer (score 0):

`gsub(" - ", " ", df2$text)` is looking for a space, then a dash, then a space. The examples you give like `app- le` don't have a space before the dash, so they won't match. If you want to match a space next to a dash only if it's there, us `?` to quantify the space:

```
df2 = read.table(text = 'Id|text
1|I have learnt abc- d in school.
2|I want app- le.
3|Going to sc- hool is fun', sep = "|", header = TRUE)

gsub(" ?- ?", " ", df2$text)
# [1] "I have learnt abc d in school." "I want app le."                 "Going to sc hool is fun"

## Maybe you want to replace it with nothing, not with a space?
gsub(" ?- ?", "", df2$text)
# [1] "I have learnt abcd in school." "I want apple."                 "Going to school is fun"
```

Since your example doesn't include any line breaks, I can't really tell what the issue is.

Comment: Hey @Gregor Thomas , is there anyway i could contact you and i share you my codes and what i have done?

Comment: Sorry, not available for private tutoring currently.

Comment: Alright. Because don't really know how to explain it here with the issue. Just hope sharing the code what I have done for this could give you a better understanding for it.

Comment: Making a minimal reproducible example is the key to good debugging. If you can do that, 80% of the time you figure out the mistake yourself, and the rest of the time you have something nice to make a question on here and get more help. I'd highly recommend [Jenny Bryan's talk on this](https://rstudio.com/resources/rstudioconf-2020/object-of-type-closure-is-not-subsettable/). If you can make an example showing what you've got and the code you're using, post it in a new question.

Comment: Using `dput()` to share data is also very good, to make sure we have exactly the same input. E.g., instead of showing my the print of `df2`, put the output from `dput(df2)` (or use a subset like `dput(df2[1:10, ])`).

Comment: Alright. I will try using dput() later on and post a new question. Because I did tried some of the solution given online and it still gives the same result. I have been trying for hours and still stuck that's why I post a question, trying my best to give the best explanation the current situation I'm currently facing.